# How are the tag manager and analytics connected?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using the data layer of the tag manager for using the analycits app tracking. I'm wondering where the data are send to analytics. From my app or on the server side of the tag manager?

Everythings works fine so far, but I would like to know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all run on the client, server side of tag manager just builds & deploys it.

Comment: Do you have any references for that?

Comment: There's a broad strokes overview of the analytics platform here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/ Tag manager is just an alternate way of implementing analytics in your app/site.